# ValueError: X has 42 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 1998 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to ML and python. I am using Random Forest Classifier as my model. Here is the issue I'm facing . All my cell run smoothly except the last cell. I used LabelEncoder as well as One-Hot Encoder to convert my categorical columns and I get the following error not sure where in my code I'm messing up. I am building a Model to predict the probability that a planned change is going to fail

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[69], line 49
     46 d, rfc_loaded = joblib.load(filename)
     48 # Make Predictions
---> 49 prediction_df['predict'] = pd.DataFrame(rfc_loaded.predict(prediction_df))
     51 prediction_df['probability'] = pd.DataFrame(rfc_loaded.predict_proba(prediction_df) [:, 1])
     53 count=sum(prediction_df['predict'] ==1 )

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py:821, in ForestClassifier.predict(self, X)
    800 def predict(self, X):
    801     """
    802     Predict class for X.
    803 
   (...)
    819         The predicted classes.
    820     """
--> 821     proba = self.predict_proba(X)
    823     if self.n_outputs_ == 1:
    824         return self.classes_.take(np.argmax(proba, axis=1), axis=0)

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py:863, in ForestClassifier.predict_proba(self, X)
    861 check_is_fitted(self)
    862 # Check data
--> 863 X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
...
    360         f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    361         f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."
    362     )

ValueError: X has 42 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 1998 features as input.
```

In the beginning, I sue several technique to help balance the data for the minority class.

```
# load the dataset 
df = pd.read_csv("training v.3.csv", encoding='cp1252')

# Keep the neccessary columns that's needed
cols_to_keep = [
    "close_code",
    "assignment_group",
    "assignment_group_category",
    "cmdb_ci",
    "type",
    "sys_created_on_day_of_week",
    "cab_required",
    "cmdb_ci.environment",
    "size_backout",
]

df = df[cols_to_keep]

# drop rows with missing values
df = df.dropna()

# Define features & labels
feat = df.drop(columns=["close_code"])
label = df["close_code"]

# one-hot encoding of the categotical columns
feature = pd.get_dummies(feat, columns=feat.columns)


# initialize the one-hot encoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown="ignore")

# fit the hot encoder to the categorical variables
encoder.fit(feature)

# Transform the categorical variables
X_train_encoded = encoder.transform(feature)

# Scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
feature_encoded = scaler.fit_transform(X_train_encoded)

# Split the data into a training set and a test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    feature_encoded, label, train_size=0.65, test_size=0.35, random_state=42
)


rom collections import Counter

# Get the class counts
counts = Counter(y_train)

# Determine the minority class
minority_class_label = min(counts, key=counts.get)

# Define sampling_strategy
sampling_strategy = {minority_class_label: int(counts[minority_class_label])}

from imblearn.combine import SMOTETomek

# Apply SMOTE-TOMEK
smt = SMOTETomek(sampling_strategy=sampling_strategy)
X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled = smt.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)


# Train the Random Forest Classifier on the oversampled data
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(
    n_estimators=1600,
    min_samples_split=6,
    min_samples_leaf=1,
    max_depth=15,
    class_weight="balanced",
)

# train the classifier on the oversampled train data
rfc.fit(X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled)

# Evaluate the classifier on the test set
y_pred = rfc.predict(X_test)

# print the feature importances
for name, importance in zip(feat, rfc.feature_importances_):
    print(name, "=", importance)

# # print out the classification report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

import joblib
from sklearn import preprocessing

rfc_loaded = RandomForestClassifier()

X_train_encoded = X_train_encoded[:len(y_train_resampled), :]
rfc_loaded.fit(X_train_encoded, y_train_resampled)

d = preprocessing.LabelEncoder

i = [d, rfc_loaded]

filename = 'rfc_model.model'
joblib.dump(i, filename)

prediction_df = pd.read_csv("prediction.csv", encoding='cp1252')

# Load the model
d, rfc_loaded = joblib.load(filename)



# Drop rows with missing values
# prediction_df = prediction_df.dropna

cols_to_keep = [
    "assignment_group",
    "assignment_group.u_accenture_category",
    "cmdb_ci",
    "type",
    "sys_created_on_day_of_week",
    "cab_required",
    "cmdb_ci.environment",
    "size_backout"
]

prediction_df=prediction_df[cols_to_keep]

prediction_deep = prediction_df.copy(deep=True)

# initialize the one-hot encoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown="ignore")

# fit the hot encoder to the categorical variables
encoder.fit(prediction_df)

# Transform the categorical variables
X_train_encoded = encoder.transform(prediction_df)


# Read Target Column
prediction_df['target'] = 0

# Set Numerical Columns
numerical_columns = [col for col in prediction_df.columns if                     
                    (prediction_df[col].dtype == 'int64' or prediction_df[col].dtype == 'float64') and col != 'target']

# One-Hot Encode the categorical variables
prediction_df = pd.get_dummies(prediction_df)

# Scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
prediction_df = scaler.fit_transform(prediction_df)


filename = 'rfc_model.model'
# Load the model
d, rfc_loaded = joblib.load(filename)

# Make Predictions
prediction_df['predict'] = pd.DataFrame(rfc_loaded.predict(prediction_df))

prediction_df['probability'] = pd.DataFrame(rfc_loaded.predict_proba(prediction_df) [:, 1])

count=sum(prediction_df['predict'] ==1 )

print("Check" , count)

prediction_df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\shaina.bowser\OneDrive - Accenture\Desktop\ProjectLemonade\results.csv")
```

I printed out my shapes and got

```
X_train.shape (3515, 1998)
X_train_resample.shape (3487, 1998)
X_test.shape (1894, 1998)
```

Comment: What's the shape of `prediction_df`? Probably the categories aren't the same, so `pd.get_dummies` leads to differing numbers of columns.

Comment: the shape of ```prediction_df``` is ```(21, 23)``` looking at  both dataset they have the same categories

Comment: You report that `prediction_df` has 23 columns, but at predict time it has 42 (according to the error message), but the model is expecting 1998.  Why the discrepancy?  I still suspect a difference in present categories (in the features, not the target), especially now seeing that you only have 21 rows.